# Entry points and their replacement

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following text:

```
...
<tr>
<td>123AB:</td>
<td>173.2 von 5000 MB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123ABC:</td>
<td>3029.7 von 5000 MB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
...
```

and I am trying to get it in the following format:

```
173.2 - A
3029.7 - B
```

i.e. get the values before `von 5000 MB</td>` and then write the text.  I'm trying to get it in the following way:

`sed -En 's/.*<td>(.*) von 5000.*/\1 - A/p' ./file.txt`

Output:

```
173.2 - A
3029.7 - A
```

this command works globally - and that's correct; I just don't know how to make a replacement only for the first entry and then the other one for the second. Can anyone show me the correct example? Thx!

P.S. I have BSD sed.

Answer (score 0):

The `sed` editor is not good with states. Consider using 'awk', which is more flexible with respect to conditional logic:

```
awk '
/<td>.* von 5000/ { n++ ; print gensub(".*<td>(.*) von 5000.*", "\\1 -", 1), n == 1 ? "A" : "B" } 
'
```

Comment: You're probably right, and I'll be fine with any options.
I get the next error. 

```awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 /<td>.* von 5000/ { n++ ; print gensub(".*<td>(.*) von 5000.*", "\\1 -", 1), n >>>  == <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1```

Comment: @KarlsD command works on my Mint19 (awk 4.1.4). What OS, awk version and shell are you using ?

Comment: >awk --version;  
  awk version 20070501;
OS X, and it looks like I have a very old version )